# Probability A intersection B explained

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Could you please verify my understanding of intersection and conditional probability?
[image: Understanding Intersection in probability]

Comment: It would help get an answer quicker and help future readers search for your problem if you transcribed your problem rather than posting a picture of it

Comment: I will convert it to text instead of picture as soon as possible. I did it because I was in hurry.

Comment: Your understanding of $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A|B)$ are correct